# Not able to execute Pyspark script using spark action in Oozie - Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, oozie, instantiationexception

I am facing below error while running **spark action through oozie workflow** on an EMR 5.14 cluster:

**pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog'"**
My Pyspark script runs fine when executed as a normal spark job but is not being executed via Oozie
Pyspark Program:-

```
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("PysparkTest").config("hive.support.quoted.identifiers", "none").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();
    sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
    sqlContext.sql("show databases").show()
```

I have created a workflow.xml and job.properties taking reference from the [LINK](https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2017/06/30/scheduling-spark-job-written-pyspark-sparkr-yarn-oozie/).

I copied all the spark and hive related configuration file under the same directory($SPARK_CONF_DIR/).
Hive is also configured to use MySQL for the metastore.

**It will be great if you can help me figure out the problem which I am facing when running this Pyspark program as a jar file in an Oozie spark action.**

Answer (score 0):

`Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog'` This means the `Catalog` jar its trying find is not is ooziesharelib spark directory.

Please add the following property in your `job.properties` file.

```
oozie.action.sharelib.for.spark=hive,spark,hcatalog
```

Also can you please post the whole log?

And if possible could you please run the same on EMR 5.29, I have faced few jar issue on 5.26 and the lower version while running PySpark.